# BSOD WIndows 8.1 -> Windows 10

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, bsod

Upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1. Computer is rebooting on it's own and I am not sure why. Uninstalled everything and reinstalled it using the latest one. Drivers all seem to be working without a problem. Here is the Debug file but I need a little help trying to figure out what is causing the crash. The memory test shows all is fine and no hardware issues.

Blue screen is telling me PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA

```
    Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10240.9 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\Public\Downloads\112915-16781-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
No .natvis files found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers.
Windows 10 Kernel Version 10586 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 10586.11.amd64fre.th2_release.151112-1900
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`e727a000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`e7558c70
Debug session time: Sun Nov 29 14:01:40.462 2015 (UTC - 5:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:01:03.216
Loading Kernel Symbols
.

Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.

..............................................................
................................................................
......................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
..........
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 50, {fffff6fb400037a8, 0, 0, 6}

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for bcmwl63a.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for bcmwl63a.sys

Could not read faulting driver name
Probably caused by : bcmwl63a.sys ( bcmwl63a+8e64f )

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I looked up this driver **bcmwl63a.sys** and I have the most recent of everything but I can't figure out why it keeps crashing.

Wireless Driver: Broadcom
Driver Date: 7/30/2015
**Driver Version: 7.35.295.0**

Comment: after fixing symbols, run **!analyze -v** again.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have updated the log.

Comment: bcmwl63a.sys = broadcom Wifi driver. which driver version do you use?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Updated bottom of the post. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: this driver is not the newest one. Try the driver **7.35.308.0**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/673laypzi273fbh/Drivers_7.35.308.0.7z?dl=1

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried one for Windows 7 x64 from 2012 and seems to be working now. I will DL this one and add it into my library incase this one goes.

The working one was is this one for now: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=51DM4

Been working for 2 days without a crash so far. Thanks.

This could probably be marked as the answer.

Comment: ok, report back in 2-3 days if the your device is still stable.

Comment: is the PC stable with the old Win7 drivers?

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes seems to be stable. No crashes or problems. That seamed to have done the trick. Thanks.

Comment: this is wired. Can you also please try driver 7.35.333.0 from my dropbox? https://www.dropbox.com/s/6h3830cwetl3kad/Drivers_7.35.333.0.7z?dl=0 It also includes the debug symbols for the drivers, so if you get a new crash, in Windbg add the path to the PDBs to the symbols configuration to see more details.

Comment: @magicandre1981 it's wired or weird? I think I am using a earlier version from Dell's site from back in October of 2012. I will have to get the number and get back to you.

Comment: "weird" *d'oh* please try the new driver. Because of the inclded debug symbols we can get more details if they also crash. If you still get issues you can go back to the Win7 drivers

Comment: @magicandre1981 sorry I have been really busy with work. I got a chance to try the driver and it works like a charm. Funny how it shows up as a broadcom driver and not the DW1530. LOL